# Ordinal logistic regression prediction and accuracy using statsmodels

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, prediction, statsmodels

I am trying to do a ordinal logistic regression analysis using statsmodels. However, the predictions I'm getting are vastly different from that I get when using SciKit-Learn `LogisticRegression`.

I'm using a dataset similar to the following. The aim is to predict the `quality` (on a scale of `1-10`) based on the composition of `chlorides` and `sulphates`.

| chlorides | sulphates | quality |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.076 | 0.56 | 5 |
| 0.098 | 0.68 | 5 |
| 0.092 | 0.65 | 5 |
| 0.075 | 0.58 | 6 |
| 0.076 | 0.56 | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel

y = df['quality']
X = df[['chlorides', 'sulphates']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=20)

mod_probe = OrderedModel(y_train, X_train, distr='logit')
res_log = mod_probe.fit(method='bgfs')

predicted = res_log.model.predict(res_log.params, np.array(X_test)[:, None])
```

`predicted` sample:

```
array([[[0.00394536, 0.02194635, 0.32950146, 0.47302334, 0.15847723,
         0.01310626]],

       [[0.01405662, 0.07326043, 0.57761266, 0.2806573 , 0.05073693,
         0.00367607]],

       [[0.02683372, 0.12930636, 0.63716285, 0.17780338, 0.02698959,
         0.0019041 ]],

       ...,
```

When I do

```
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and unknown targets
```

I have done many hours of searching on this but can't seem to crack it. Any help would be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Classification metrics requires input with limited classes for eg if class range is [0,2] then it would require values like 0,1,2 but in your case you give 0.001,0.5 etc. The logits outputs continuous values but classification metrices require discrete value. to fix this add `predicted = list(map(round, predicted ))`  after the line where you perform prediction and that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Classification metrics requires input with limited classes for eg if class range is [0,2] then it would require values like 0,1,2 but in your case you give 0.001,0.5 etc. The logits outputs continuous values but classification metrices require discrete value. Your Output is sparse vector of probability distribution over all the class. To fix it you could use `np.argmax`.

Update:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel

y = df['quality']
X = df[['chlorides', 'sulphates']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=20)

mod_probe = OrderedModel(y_train, X_train, distr='logit')
res_log = mod_probe.fit(method='bfgs')

predicted = res_log.model.predict(res_log.params, np.array(X_test)) #removed the slicing part
preds = [np.argmax(x) for x in predicted]
```

What changed :

- Removed the slicing part since all it did was expand dims which i dont think is necessarily needed but keep it if you get error (The code will work even if you keep the slicing part).
- Added `preds = [np.argmax(x) for x in predicted]` which iterates over the predicted array and takes the index of which has max value.

After this you could use `metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, preds).`

Comment: Unfortunately I got a little too excited too quickly. When I do `predicted = list(map(round, predicted ))` I get the error `TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The tried the new code and it compiles, but I'm not sure if it's correct because the accuracy I am getting with my dataset is 0.003125 (less than 1%) and it seems way off from the ones I get with Sci-Kit Learn `LogisticRegression` (around 60%).

Comment: yeah i was getting low accuracy too. Could you tell me what exactly is the output of the predict method, Cuz what i assumed is that its sparse probability distribution over class since if we  add those values it gave me 1, thats why i used np.argmax. tell me if i am wrong.